# test a multi-step registration system using SpecFlow

Tags: bdd, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow whilst writing an asp.net mvc 3 website. The registration system in the site consists of two views. 
the first view asks for basic information e.g eMail, password and location, whilst the second view asks the user for the type of account (developer or standard user) and then name, address etc.

In SpecFlow terms then I have one feature Registration and two succeeding senarios, registering as a developer and as a standard user. 
if this was one view I could test this using something like:
given I am on the registration page
when I enter Data1
and I enter data2
and I click the next button
then the registration should be successfull
as I have two views is it best practice to chain several given, when, and, then statements or is there a better way of doing something like this?
Any help apreciated.
Sean

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid mentioning the different pages within the feature file, and handle that at the step definition level instead, e.g.

```
Given I am registering
When I fill in my basic information
And I choose to register as a developer
Then I should be registered as a developer

Given I am registering
When I fill in my basic information
And I choose to register as a standard user
Then I should be registered as a standard user
```